# problem booting with failed software RAID 1

Tags: raid

I have been experimenting with a software RAID 1 installation of ubuntu 12.04 LTS in virtualbox, but am having some issues here.

What I basically did: 2 disks in RAID 1. Both disks contain a mirrored partition that has /boot and a mirrored partition that contains an encrypted LVM. All this so far so good, it boots perfectly after install.

When I decide then to try to remove one of both disks in virtualbox, it just says "waiting for encrypted source" (or something along those lines, can't remember exactly).

After several more minutes, it drops to an initramfs console, where I am stuck... And yes, I choose the option boot in degraded mode during install, I also checked in the initramfstools/conf.d, it states bootdegraded=true.

What am I doing wrong here? I thought a raid 1 was supposed to boot perfectly even if one disk completely disappears? Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem (in hardware, not virtualbox) while setting up an unencrypted, bootable 14.04 RAID1. Basically, I needed to add a sleep script to allow mdadm sufficient time to assemble a degraded device. See the instructions in section 6.1 [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/660023/how-to-install-ubuntu-14-04-64-bit-with-a-dual-boot-raid-1-partition-on-an-uefi).