# Installation Issues with Flash Drive

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, live-usb, drive

Ubuntu doesn't allow me to fully install it because at the end when it asks, "Ubuntu needs to restart. Would you like to do it now?", without hesitation I click continue. Upon rebooting it prompts me a 2nd time if I want to install or try it out.

If I remove the flash drive after rebooting, I get a message saying the computer has no OS.

Comment: All I have done is transition from windows to ubuntu and deleted windows. That was an option provided by ubuntu.

Comment: yeah thats what i keep getting so where do i go to delete that media file

Comment: without the flashdrive ubuntu wont run

Comment: it will say my computer dont have an os

Comment: If i didnt install correctly how am i on right now the flashdrive allows me be on but i think the computer thinks thats my internal

Comment: i wish i could show you what it says on my files i have a screenshot

Comment: on my devices is had computer then  2 volumes one is 16gb and one is 496gb and it wont let me use that 495 gb and that 16 is not the one that is running ubuntu right now

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo grub-install /dev/sda
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of `/cow'.

Comment: i continue to get errors all over the board cause nothing in the answer is in order if u dont mine could u put them in order for me please it would be a great help

Comment: grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of `/cow'

Comment: where do you want me to show you this screenshot

Comment: Shane, could you [edit] your question and copy-paste all the relevant data from the comments into your question?  **:-)**

Answer (score 0):

It might be a (U)EFI problem. Do you know if your computer boots in UEFI (needs an EFI partition) or CSM (needs an MBR)? If the former, you could have a look at my question here ([How to install Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit with a dual-boot RAID 1 partition on an UEFI/GPT system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/660023/how-to-install-ubuntu-14-04-64-bit-with-a-dual-boot-raid-1-partition-on-an-uefi)) and ignore the RAID parts. Good luck!