# Dual boot Ubuntu 16.04/WIndows 10 with hardware RAID

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, raid

Long story short: 
Want dual boot 
Using live USB
Installer won't recognize Windows OS as present 
Won't list system disk as possible install location 
System disk and all partitions shown in GParted
hibernate /off 
swap /off 
hardware RAID 1 6TB LD (x2 3TB) 
400GB unallocated HDD space on system disk 
AMD Phenom II X4 3.4GHz 
16GB RAM 
64-bit Windows 10 OS 
ASUS M5A97 R2.0 Motherboard with RAID 
Please assist. I've seen a few options but I'm afraid of messing up my RAID configuration in Windows. Not to mention the OS itself.

Comment: Is it really hardware RAID or separate controller card, or BIOS RAID also known as "FakeRAID". https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2229126 and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/660023/how-to-install-ubuntu-14-04-64-bit-with-a-dual-boot-raid-1-partition-on-an-uefi

Comment: I'm going to say it's probably the BIOS RAID since it's integrated with the motherboard. This is my first time with a RAID setup. Will the instructions in those threads solve my issues? I'm afraid of losing my data.

Comment: You always should have backups, so then no worries. Hard drives do fail, users make mistakes as they may not fully understand what a command does. Backups allow you to recovery. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto  I really do not know RAID, it is more for maintaining system up on servers, that have regular backup procedures. If you want speed generally SSD is better.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't really help answer my question. I'm aware I should have backups but I don't have the resources right now. I'm running RAID to decrease read/write times for gaming.

Comment: Did you review links on RAID installs? Have you turned off fast start up in Windows so installer can see that you do have Windows installed. Only use Windows to shrink the Windows NTFS partition to make unallocated space and reboot so it can run chkdsk. Most have said then installer works, but grub does not install and you then have to do a grub repair to install it.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair