# GRUB not installing on Ubuntu 18.04+GPT+RAID 1 (mirroring)

Tags: grub2, system-installation, raid, gpt

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 with GPT and RAID1 (mirroring) on 2 same size disks, with no other OS installed, but installation fails at GRUB. Is this an Ubuntu bug!? By default GRUB should install on both disks (sda&sdb), but the installer is failing to recognize the disks and throwing errors.

[image: Ubuntu 18.04 partitions with RAID]

[image: Grub installation error on ubuntu18.04-GPT-RAID1]

Note: I tried including the bios-grub partition into RAID but it didn't work, and same error.

Let me know any suggestion to resolve this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Ubuntu 14.04/16.04 64-bit with a dual-boot RAID 1 partition on an UEFI/GPT system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/660023/how-to-install-ubuntu-14-04-16-04-64-bit-with-a-dual-boot-raid-1-partition-on-an)

Comment: @Yufenyuy Veyeh Dider,  I am not looking for dual boot with windows, its just ubuntu only, and that's a lot of steps! for fixing a ubuntu bug!.

Answer (score 0):

RED FLAG

Simular issue here with secure boot enabled and dual boot with Ten (GPT), when clicking install Ubuntu, Ubiquity won't install Grud near the end and a fatal error occurs ending the install. Passing by Try Ubuntu works normally.

This bug has been present for more than a month in all flavors of DD (1709,19H1,20H1). Works normally when not dual boot. Bootline is tweaked with iommu=soft. With or without MOK Manager. The fatal error was sent twice via Ubiquity 3 weeks ago (Mate and U).