# How to Install Bionic Beaver on m.2 SSD

Tags: server, 18.04, nvme

I am attempting to install ubuntu 18.04 server on a computer with 3 nvme m.2 SSD's. I am trying to use raid 5. After partitioning the system as follows

```
RAID5 device #0 - 4.0 GB Linux Software RAID Array
     #1             4.0 GB     K  swap     swap
RAID5 device #1 - 1.0 TB Linux Software RAID Array
     #1             1.0 TB     K  ext4     /
/dev/nvme0n1 - 512.1 GB INTEL SSDPEKNW512GB
     #1  primary    2.0 GB     K  raid
     #2  primary  510.1 GB     K  raid
/dev/nvme1n1 - 512.1 GB INTEL SSDPEKNW512GB
     #1  primary    2.0 GB     K  raid
     #2  primary  510.1 GB     K  raid
/dev/nvme2n1 - 512.1 GB INTEL SSDPEKNW512GB
     #1  primary    2.0 GB     K  raid
     #2  primary  510.1 GB     K  raid
```

I get this error right after.

```
An installation step failed you can try to run the failing item again from the menu or skip it and choose something else the failing step is: Install the system
```

I have tried some other partitioning patterns but nothing that works

Comment: There's no need for a swap partition in 18.04. And you're system is likely UEFI therefore and EFI partition is a requirement.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Okay So do I make the EFI In a software raid device as in RAID5 Device #0 Or does this happen before raid

Comment: I know almost nothing about RAID but logic tells me the firmware must see the EFI partition before anything OS/software related/dependent so, before? It's how UEFI works

Comment: Do not know RAID, but some info here? https://askubuntu.com/questions/660023/how-to-install-ubuntu-14-04-16-04-64-bit-with-a-dual-boot-raid-1-partition-on-an

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out my problem. I needed the boot flag for my second primary partition on each device

```
RAID5 device #0 - 4.0 GB Linux Software RAID Array
     #1             4.0 GB     K  swap     swap
RAID5 device #1 - 1.0 TB Linux Software RAID Array
     #1             1.0 TB     K  ext4     /
/dev/nvme0n1 - 512.1 GB INTEL SSDPEKNW512GB
     #1  primary    2.0 GB     K  raid
     #2  primary  510.1 GB  B  K  raid
/dev/nvme1n1 - 512.1 GB INTEL SSDPEKNW512GB
     #1  primary    2.0 GB     K  raid
     #2  primary  510.1 GB  B  K  raid
/dev/nvme2n1 - 512.1 GB INTEL SSDPEKNW512GB
     #1  primary    2.0 GB     K  raid
     #2  primary  510.1 GB  B  K  raid
```